# Wordpress (custom) hooks execution order

Tags: php, wordpress, hook, custom-fields

I'm creating a wordpress plugin in a wordpress instance full of unknown plugins. I need to perform some checks and actions after custom fields have been saved to DB. Is there a way to show each executed hook in order to use (or create) the right one to call my function?

Answer (score 0):

Using this function it's possible to print (or write to file) the complete hooks execution order:

```
add_action( 'all', function ( $tag ) {
    static $hooks = array();
    if ( did_action( $tag ) ) {
        $hooks[] = $tag;
    }
    if ( 'shutdown' === $tag ) {
        myLogToFileFunction(print_r( $hooks,1 ));
    }
} );
```

For example, in a 5.7.2 Wordpress instance

```
[...]
    
[203] => wp_update_site
[204] => wpmu_blog_updated
[205] => publish_to_publish
[206] => publish_seminari-on-line
[207] => edit_post_seminari-on-line
[208] => edit_post
[209] => post_updated
[210] => parse_tax_query
[211] => parse_query
[212] => pre_get_posts
[213] => parse_tax_query
[214] => posts_selection
[215] => save_post_seminari-on-line
[216] => save_post

[217] => my_custom_hook

[218] => action_scheduler_stored_action
[219] => wp_insert_post
[220] => wp_after_insert_post
[221] => update_post_meta
[222] => update_postmeta
[223] => updated_post_meta
[224] => updated_postmeta
[225] => shutdown
[...]
```

In my case I needed to add a custom hook at the end of the method called by the save-post hook.